# Как проверить корректность имени создаваемого файла?

Tags: c#

Есть строка, в которой пользователь указал имя создаваемого файла. Есть необходимость проверить корректность имени. Если есть недопустимые символы, то заменить их, к примеру на "_". try не подходит, т.к. причин исключений при создании файла много (нет места на жестком диске,  нет прав на создание в данной директории и т.д.). Подскажите, как проверить корректность имени?

Comment: Возможно тут может помочь [Метод Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/422111/276994

Comment: @Grundy надо ещё учесть всякие `COM`, `LPT` и пр.

Comment: @alexolut: А также `\\server\...`

Comment: @VladD короче, проще не создавать файл вовсе :-D

Comment: Предположу, что вам нужно вот это: [`FileDialog.ValidateNames`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.filedialog.validatenames(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @alexolut, либо наоборот создать и поймать исключение :)

Comment: Использую Path.CheckInvalidPathChars. Вызов через рефлексию. Писалось давно, может чего поменялось уже.

Comment: regexpressions ? если есть специфика названия - исключи не нужные символы и всё

Comment: Замена на `_` — плохая идея. Например потому, что уже может существовать файл или каталог с таким (новым) именем.

Comment: Что вы хотите получить такой проверкой? Ну проверите вы что имя не содержит недопустимых символов или замените таковые допустимыми и что? Это не избавит от исключений при совпадении имен (или еще хуже - вы перезапишете не свой файл), при недостатке прав или запрете доступа, при банальном сбое физического диска или аппаратного рейда. Если вас это устраивает, то берете метод из первого комментария и замещаете каждый совпавший символ имени на другой допустимый по вашему выбору.

Comment: "try не подходит, т.к. причин исключений при создании файла много" - никто не просит учитывать все исключения. При указании некорректного пути к файлу, методы работы с файлами генерируют вполне конкретное ArgumentException

Comment: VladD, мне нужно проверить только корректность имени, не более... Уникальность имени - это совсем другой вопрос.

Comment: @АлександрПузанов а сложность то в чем, по идее ведь нужно проверить просто имя файла, возможно, еще и путь к файлу, если это необходимо или я чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: Вопрос хороший, здесь скорее интерес к подходу других разработчиков.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для себя я сделал вот такой метод расширения:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// удаляет все символы которые не разрешены в именах файлов
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="file_name"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static String RemoveInvalidChars(this String file_name)
    {
        foreach (Char invalid_char in Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars())
        {
            file_name = file_name.Replace(oldValue: invalid_char.ToString(), newValue: "");
        }
        return file_name;
    }
```

в параметр newValue можете добавить символ по своему усмотрению

Если хотите одной строкой то можно вот так:

```
String new_file_name = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars().Aggregate(invalid_file_name, (current, invalid_char) => current.Replace(invalid_char.ToString(), "_"));
```

Comment: Есть нюанс. Если передать в file_name весь путь, вырежет все слеши и двоеточие за одно. В этом случае лучше использовать `Path.GetInvalidPathChars()`

Answer (score 9):

как-то так

```
/// <summary>
/// Проверка корректности имени файла
/// </summary>
/// <param name="name">Проверяемое имя</param>        
public static bool ValidateFileName(string name)
{
    try
    {
        FileStream fs = File.Open(name, FileMode.Open);
        if (fs != null) fs.Close();
    }
    catch (ArgumentException)
    {
        return false;//имя файла введено некорректно
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    {                
        return true;//имя файла введено корректно, но файл не существует
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        return true;//имя файла введено корректно, но файл недоступен
    }
    return true;//имя файла введено корректно
}

/// <summary>
/// Проверка корректности имени файла с предложением исправленного имени
/// </summary>
/// <param name="name">Проверяемое имя</param>
/// <param name="corrected_name">Предлагаемое исправленное имя</param>        
public static bool ValidateFileName(string name,out string corrected_name)
{
    try
    {
        FileStream fs = File.Open(name, FileMode.Open);
        if (fs != null) fs.Close();
    }
    catch (ArgumentException)//имя файла введено некорректно
    {
        //пытаемся исправить имя
        char[] banned = System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (char c in name)
        {
            if (banned.Contains(c)) sb.Append('_');
            else sb.Append(c);
        }

        if (ValidateFileName(sb.ToString()) != false)
        {
            //удалось исправить имя
            corrected_name = sb.ToString();
        }
        else corrected_name = "";//не удалось исправить имя (видимо это зарезервированное имя типа CON)
        return false;
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    {
        corrected_name = "";
        return true;//имя файла введено корректно, но файл не существует
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        corrected_name = "";
        return true;//имя файла введено корректно, но файл недоступен
    }
    corrected_name = "";
    return true;//имя файла введено корректно
}
```

Но на самом деле, в настольных приложениях лучше так не делать, а использовать для ввода имени SaveFileDialog с включенной проверкой корректности. Так что это в основном для служб или веб-приложений.

Answer (score 1):

Проверку что не указано недопустимых символов в имени файла или пути можно сделать так:

```
private static bool IsValidFilename(string fileName)
{
    var invalidChars = string.Join("", Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars());
    var regex = new Regex("[" + Regex.Escape(string.Join("", invalidChars)) + "]");

    return !regex.IsMatch(fileName);
}

private static bool IsValidFilePath(string path)
{
    var invalidChars = string.Join("", Path.GetInvalidPathChars());
    var regex = new Regex("[" + Regex.Escape(string.Join("", invalidChars)) + "]");

    return !regex.IsMatch(path);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
     foreach (var invalidFileNameChar in Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars())
     {
         var name = "Имя" + invalidFileNameChar;
         Console.WriteLine($"{name} --> {IsValidFileName(name)}");
     }

     Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 40));

     foreach (var invalidFilePathChar in Path.GetInvalidPathChars())
     {
         var path = @"C:\my.txt" + invalidFilePathChar;
         Console.WriteLine($"{path} --> {IsValidFilePath(path)}");
     }   
}
```